# How to add row by clicking a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a html table in which there is no entry and i have made javascript functions to add new rows in the table. I followed this link http://mrbool.com/how-to-add-edit-and-delete-rows-of-a-html-table-with-jquery/26721 but i don't know where is the problem that it is not adding any row. Even on clicking button 'new' nothing happens. I have added all js files and images but still there is problem and i am not able to uderstand where is the problem.
 this is my html table

```
<head>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="function.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="btnAddd">New</button> 
    <table id="tblData">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Phone</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
        </table>
</body>
```

and my function.js file is this

```
    function Add() {
        $("#tblData tbody")
                .append(
                        "<tr>"
                                + "<td><input type='text'/></td>"
                                + "<td><input type='text'/></td>"
                                + "<td><input type='text'/></td>"
                                + "<td><img src='disk.png' class='btnSave'><img src='delete.png' class='btnDelete'/></td>"
                                + "</tr>");
        $(".btnSave").bind("click", Save);
        $(".btnDelete").bind("click", Delete);
    };

    function Save() {
        var par = $(this).parent().parent();
        var tdName = par.children("td:nth-child(1)");
        var tdPhone = par.children("td:nth-child(2)");
        var tdEmail = par.children("td:nth-child(3)");
        var tdButtons = par.children("td:nth-child(4)");
        tdName.html(tdName.children("input[type=text]").val());
        tdPhone.html(tdPhone.children("input[type=text]").val());
        tdEmail.html(tdEmail.children("input[type=text]").val());
        tdButtons
                .html("<img src='images/delete.png' class='btnDelete'/><img src='images/pencil.png' class='btnEdit'/>");
        $(".btnEdit").bind("click", Edit);
        $(".btnDelete").bind("click", Delete);
    };
function Delete() {
    var par = $(this).parent().parent();
    par.remove();
}; 


$(function() {
    $(".btnEdit").bind("click", Edit);
    $(".btnDelete").bind("click", Delete);
    $("#btnAdd").bind("click", Add);
});
```

Please help me to solve this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can we get a fiddle?

Comment: I think everything is fine. I followed as it is told in the link

Comment: If everything was fine, it would work.

Comment: you have typo in add button id.

Comment: maybe your explorer are not getting the references, could you try to change, the id 'tblData' move to <tbody> and in your function.js change the ('#tblData tbody') to ('#tblData')

Answer (score 4):

your add button's id is: Addd but you used #add in your jquery code.

change #Add to #Addd in jquery part.

Answer (score 0):

First correct spelling of button, remove extra 'd' from 'Add'

```
<button id="btnAdd">New</button>
```

and you need not to bind click event for every delete / edit button added in row. Also, use `.on()` to bind click event for dynamically added button. See below code

```
function Add() {
        $("#tblData tbody")
                .append(
                        "<tr>"
                                + "<td><input type='text'/></td>"
                                + "<td><input type='text'/></td>"
                                + "<td><input type='text'/></td>"
                                + "<td><img src='disk.png' class='btnSave'><img src='delete.png' class='btnDelete'/></td>"
                                + "</tr>");
    };

    function Save() {
        var par = $(this).parent().parent();
        var tdName = par.children("td:nth-child(1)");
        var tdPhone = par.children("td:nth-child(2)");
        var tdEmail = par.children("td:nth-child(3)");
        var tdButtons = par.children("td:nth-child(4)");
        tdName.html(tdName.children("input[type=text]").val());
        tdPhone.html(tdPhone.children("input[type=text]").val());
        tdEmail.html(tdEmail.children("input[type=text]").val());
        tdButtons
                .html("<img src='images/delete.png' class='btnDelete'/><img src='images/pencil.png' class='btnEdit'/>");

    };
function Delete() {
    //use closest to find parent TR
    var par = $(this).closest("tr");
    par.remove();
}; 


$(function() {
    $(".btnEdit").bind("click", Edit);
    $(".btnDelete").bind("click", Delete);
    $("#btnAdd").bind("click", Add);
    //add click event for dynamically added button
    $("tblData").on("click",".btnSave", Save);
    $("tblData").on("click",".btnDelete", Delete);
    $("tblData").on("click",".btnEdit", Edit);
});
```